# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll when I tried to insert data into textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i am creating a connection to my database from from visual studio.

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class CM : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server =KIRITI; database =msdb; Integrated Security=True");

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open(); 
    String NotesMaker = TextBox1.Text;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into NOTESMAKER(NOTESMAKER) Values('"+NotesMaker+"',con)");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select@@Identity";
    con.Close();
}
}
```

I get an error at command.Executenonquery():

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

> Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, your command needs a connection.

Answer (score 4):

*Thats the first place where I have seen string concatenation causing `conn` to be part of query.*

You misplaced string quotes, your statement should be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = 
  new SqlCommand("Insert into NOTESMAKER(NOTESMAKER) Values('" + NotesMaker + "'",con);
```

In your current code, you are passing string `"Insert into NOTESMAKER(NOTESMAKER) Values('"+NotesMaker+"',con)"`, hence the connection property is not initialized and hence the exception.

You should never use string concatenation for creating queries, instead use Parameters. This will save you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Like:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into NOTESMAKER(NOTESMAKER) Values(@NotesMaker)",con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NotesMaker", NotesMaker);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You put `con` inside the quotes of the first parameter of the constructor for `SqlCommand`, thus the code is complaining because you aren't setting the Connection property of your `SqlCommand`

change

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into NOTESMAKER(NOTESMAKER) Values('"+NotesMaker+"',con)");
```

to

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into NOTESMAKER(NOTESMAKER) Values('"+NotesMaker+"')",con);
```