# C# connectivity with SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I'm facing this error when I want to connect to the SQL Server 2008 database.

ERROR:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property, has not been initialized.
>   at System.Data.Sq1Client.Sq1Command.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
>   at System.Data.Sq1Client.Sq1CommandinternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionS ource'1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.Sq1Client.Sq1Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at  WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.create_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio  201CAProjects\WindowsFormsApplicationaWindowsFormsApplicationaForm1.cs line 127

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
cmd.CommandText="insert into dbo.Student_Record
                  (
                    ID,
                    Name,
                    [Father's CNIC], 
                    [Father's Name],
                    CNIC
                  ) 
                  values 
                 ('BCSF11A003',
                  'Zargham Nazeer Malik',
                  '35202-2953923-3',
                  'Khalid Nazeer Malik',
                  '35202-2235390-5')"; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
con.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: add your code  to see what's the problem

Comment: Did you open connection before query execution? Have you defined connection of your command? Paste some code here..

Comment: As the error **clearly says**: you're probably using a `SqlCommand` or `SqlDataAdapter`, but its `Connection` property hasn't been initialized to a valid `SqlConnection`. Fix that and the error goes away

Comment: Can u tel me how to intialize property?

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText="insert into dbo.Student_Record(ID,Name,[Father's CNIC],[Father's Name],CNIC) values ('BCSF11A003','Zargham Nazeer Malik','35202-2953923-3','Khalid Nazeer Malik','35202-2235390-5')"; 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

Comment: And you need a `cmd.Connection = .......` in there somewhere! Or set the connection when creating the command: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding a connection to your command:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means you are trying to use `SqlCommand` before assigning a connection to it.

Please check. If you will include code part here then it will be more useful.

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText="insert into dbo.Student_Record(ID,Name,[Father's CNIC],[Father's Name],CNIC) values ('BCSF11A003','Zargham Nazeer Malik','35202-2953923-3','Khalid Nazeer Malik','35202-2235390-5')"; 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

Comment: Have you put connection part like this: using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))

Comment: See in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733448/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-invalidoperationexception-occurred-in-sy

Comment: Problem solved thanx man :)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work and solve your problem:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("CHANGE_THIS_TO_YOUR_CONNECTIONSTRING")){
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand(); 
cmd.CommandText="insert into dbo.Student_Record(ID,Name,[Father's CNIC],[Father's Name],CNIC) values ('BCSF11A003','Zargham Nazeer Malik','35202-2953923-3','Khalid Nazeer Malik','35202-2235390-5')"; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

}
```

You have to change CHANGE_THIS_TO_YOUR_CONNECTIONSTRING to a connectionstring.
See: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for how to find out a correct string.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this to include all the usual best practices:

```
// define the query - you should use **parameters** to avoid SQL injection
string query = "insert into dbo.Student_Record(ID, Name, [Father's CNIC], [Father's Name], CNIC) values ('BCSF11A003', 'Zargham Nazeer Malik', '35202-2953923-3', 'Khalid Nazeer Malik', '35202-2235390-5');";

// define connection string - typically read from config
string connectionString = "";

// create connection and command objects, set the "conn" connection on the "cmd" object in the constructor
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    // open connection, execute command, close connection
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```